# crawler for twitter friendships

Tags: twitter, web-crawler

I'm a graduate student whose research is complex network. I am working on a project that involves analyzing connections between users (follwing and follwers). Is it possible to write a crawler for twitter based on friendship information?

I looked around but couldn't find any things useful so far. 
thanks
Leila

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether something "out of the box" exists in this case.

But, some frameworks exist in which it is quite easy to write crawlers/spiders.

For instance:

- In Python: http://scrapy.org/
- In Java: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ThirdParty/WebCrawler/

I appreciate Scrapy for its simplicity in this case. But you might want to look for a library suited for the languages you are familiar with.